# How do you introduce probability in your Java methods – in a flexible and concise fashion?

Tags: java, probability

I've been learning Java for only about a week and a half. At this point, the only way I could think of to include an element of randomness in my code is to use the *Random* class's *nextInt* method. Below is a portion of my method:

```
Random random = new Random();
int randomInt = random.nextInt(10)+1;

[...]

if(randomInt <= 3){
System.out.println("Magnificent!");
} else if (randomInt >= 7){
System.out.println("Marvelous!");
} else {
System.out.println("Delectable!");
}
```

However, it's wordy and lacks flexibility. I would like to be able to distribute pieces of total probability of 1 to different scenarios in a concise way: thing A happens with a probability of 0.3, thing B happens with a probability of, say, 0.5, thing С happens with a probability of 0.2. How could I achieve that?

Comment: Consider using `#nextDouble` or `#nextFloat`. Then you can do things like `if (random.nextFloat() < 0.70) //70% chance`.

Comment: "lacks flexibility" what do you really mean by "flexibility"? Anything that's hard-coded isn't _flexible_, insofar as it always does the same thing. What's your actual use case?

Comment: Try creating an array with the probabilities in it, and then for each trial, see which element of the array corresponds to a random number between 0 and 1. E.g. your array is {0.1, 0.3, 0.04, 0.2, 0.36}; if your random number is 0.55, it corresponds to element 3. Then you can use the index you find for whatever purpose. It would be convenient to start with unnormalized probabilities and then normalize them in your program; this is convenient, and it avoids any problem with the input probabilities not adding up to 1.

Comment: By the way, it's possible to do interesting work with probabilities in Java, I've done it, but it's pretty clumsy. If you need to be interoperable with Java, try Kotlin instead. If you can move off the JVM, maybe try Python or R. Good luck and have fun.

Answer (score 1):

In a **general case**, you have a **set of weighted values**, which can produce a **random value based on a probability which is its weight as fraction of the total weights**. The weights can be normalized (meaning their sum is 1), or non-normalized, which is the easier assumption.

When rolling a random value out of that set, it's most efficient to check for the values with the highest probability first. Roll a random number between 0 and the total weight, then go through the values in order of their weight (descending), and check if the random number is lower than the cumulative weight -> if so, return that value.

Code:

```
public class WeightedRandom<T> {    
    private final Comparator<WeightedValue<T>> byWeight = 
        Comparator.comparing(wv -> wv.weight);
    private final Set<WeightedValue<T>> weightedValues = 
        new TreeSet<>(byWeight.reversed());

    private double totalWeight;

    void put(double weight, T value) {
        if (weight <= 0) {
            return;
        }
        totalWeight += weight;
        weightedValues.add(new WeightedValue<>(weight, value));
    }

    public T next() {
        if (weightedValues.isEmpty()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        double rnd = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(totalWeight);
        double sum = 0;
        Iterator<WeightedValue<T>> iterator = weightedValues.iterator();
        WeightedValue<T> result;
        do {
            result = iterator.next();
            sum += result.weight;
        } while (rnd > sum && iterator.hasNext());
        return result.value;
    }

    private static class WeightedValue<T> {
        final double weight;
        final T value;

        public WeightedValue(double weight, T value) {
            this.weight = weight;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WeightedRandom<String> random = new WeightedRandom<>();
    random.put(3, "AAA");
    random.put(2, "BBB");
    random.put(5, "CCC");

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        String value = random.next();
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope I'll get to know WeightedRandom some day. I can't say I understand your code at this point (I do understand what Louis Wasserman says though)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you're going to use Random.nextDouble(), and test e.g. `random.nextDouble() < 0.3` to have a probability of 0.3.

To test more than one possibility, you will need to sum some things, e.g

```
double r = random.nextDouble();
if (r < 0.3) {
   ...0.3 probability
} else if (r < 0.8) {
   ...0.5 probability
} else {
   ...0.2 probability
}
```